# Canvas ctx.rotate() with very small angles (less than 0.014) not working on Chrome, Edge

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

I just realized that Chrome (Edge too) does not perform canvas rotations `ctx.rotate()` if the angle is under `0.014` degrees. It works fine on Firefox (Windows 10).

Any ideas for a workaround? I am using 0.01 degrees in my design. Using bigger angles is not an option as it changes the design.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'), ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let cw = canvas.width = canvas.height = 600;
ctx.fillStyle = '#000000'; ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cw, cw);

let angle = 0.01;       

for (let i = 1; i <= 5000; i++) {
  ctx.translate(cw / 2, cw / 2); ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180); ctx.translate(-cw / 2, -cw / 2);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(100, 200);
  ctx.lineTo(500, 200);
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#FFFFFF';
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very weird bug that [I did report](https://crbug.com/1345038) thanks to you, and that Skia's team fixed in the latest Chrome Canary (106.0.5225.0).
Before this patch makes its way to the stable version, or for the ones willing to handle the previous versions of Chrome where this bug was happening, a very quick workaround is to use a [DOMMatrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix) to set the transform, this API doesn't seem to be affected by this bug.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'), ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let cw = canvas.width = canvas.height = 600;
ctx.fillStyle = '#000000'; ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cw, cw);

let angle = 0.01;       
const mat = new DOMMatrix();
for (let i = 1; i <= 5000; i++) {
  mat.translateSelf(cw / 2, cw / 2);
  mat.rotateSelf(angle); // DOMMatrix.rotate is in angle...
  mat.translateSelf(-cw / 2, -cw / 2);
  ctx.setTransform(mat);
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(100, 200);
  ctx.lineTo(500, 200);
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#FFFFFF';
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Really crazy, even the DOMMatrix returned by `getTransform()` is up to date, so doing `ctx.setTransform(ctx.getTransform());` in the loop does make it work... And the best is that it's not even a regression. I can see it happen in M60...

Comment: Kaiido, thank you so much! It worked perfectly :) I was thinking there's no cure to this when I asked and you answered lightning fast. I did not quite understand your comment though. Is it a better, easier way to do?

Comment: No, it's really hackish but it shows how weird this bug is. And I'm not yet done with my investigation, here is a new surprise I found: https://jsfiddle.net/f0kmuao1/ It's actually the batch of drawings that does cause an issue, which does lead to a better fix that I'll include in my answer: compose a single path and stroke it only once.

Comment: Han! Actually I missed that the single path isn't rotated correctly! What a mess you found here! I'll report that quickly.

Comment: Kaiido, even if single path rotated, I couldn't use it, as in my actual setup, I have multiple lines, polygons etc. Went with DOMMatrix method. Thank you!